# How to subscribe to an OpenProject event in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin.

I have been reading how to subscribe get notification when a project is about to be closed, using the interface [IResourceChangeListener](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResourceChangeListener.html), and using the `PRE_CLOSE` event type. The following text has been taken from the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_events.htm):

> Notifies listeners that a project is about to be closed. This event
>   can be used to extract and save necessary information from the
>   in-memory representation (e.g., session properties) of a project
>   before it is closed. (When a project is closed, the in-memory
>   representation is disposed). The workspace is locked (no resources can
>   be updated) during this event. The event contains the project that is
>   being closed.

I didn't found how to be notified when a project is about to be opened.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create your own `IResourceChangeListener` and filter the kind of delta by `IResourceDelta.OPEN`, which only affects to IProjects, and it's fired both when opening and closing a project:

```
public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
    if (event == null || event.getDelta() == null)
        return;
    event.getDelta().accept(new IResourceDeltaVisitor() {
        public boolean visit(IResourceDelta delta) throws CoreException {
            if (delta.getKind() == IResourceDelta.OPEN)
                final IResource resource = delta.getResource();
                if (!(resource instanceof IProject))
                    return;
               //do your stuff and check the project is opened or closed
        }
}
```

Useful link:
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Resource-deltas/resource-deltas.html

Comment: That does not work for the Eclipse Indigo and Project Explorer. The getKind() returns CHANGED, getFlag() returns 0 and the getResource() returns an instance of the WorkspaceRoot class.

Comment: @schnikow I ran into this too but the first delta's children are projects. For the visitor to reach those it must return true when `resource instanceof IWorkspaceRoot`.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question has been long answered, but I want to update it with a working code snippet, just in case anybody will need it. I tested it on Eclipse Luna, Indigo, and Kepler.

```
public void resourceChanged(final IResourceChangeEvent event) {
    if (event == null || event.getDelta() == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        event.getDelta().accept(new IResourceDeltaVisitor() {
            public boolean visit(final IResourceDelta delta) throws CoreException {
                IResource resource = delta.getResource();
                if (((resource.getType() & IResource.PROJECT) != 0)
                        && resource.getProject().isOpen()
                        && delta.getKind() == IResourceDelta.CHANGED
                        && ((delta.getFlags() & IResourceDelta.OPEN) != 0)) {

                    IProject project = (IProject)resource;
                    projectOpened(project);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`IResourceChangeEvent` is `POST_CHANGE` and related [`IResourceDelta`](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResourceDelta.html) kind is `IResourceDelta.CHANGED` and flags include `IResourceDelta.OPEN`.